# UPS shipping rates API error code 9368785

Tags: php, ups, ups-api

As per the UPS shipping API (API examples given on the UPS developer resources page https://www.ups.com/gec/techdocs/pdf/Rates_Pkg_Gnd.zip) I am getting the error: **Please contact UPS Freight Customer Service  for Rates at 800-333-7400 (Error Code 9368785)**

Below is the response that I am getting.

```
    [detail] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Errors] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ErrorDetail] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Severity] => Hard
                            [PrimaryErrorCode] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Code] => 9368785
                                    [Description] => Please contact UPS Freight Customer Service  for Rates at 800-333-7400
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
```

I am using the PHP example given in the above attached archive, which is provided by official UPS developer resources. The PHP example file I am using is `{ARCHIVE_FOLDER}/RatingGROUNDFREIGHTWebService/CodeSamples/Freight/PHP/SoapGroundFreightRateClient.php`

I am filling the Configuration variables with the correct values but even after that I am getting that error. Any help would be highly appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: As it turns out the account have some restrictions on the UPS end which is the reason it is not retrieving the rates like it is supposed to do. This is the error message `User is not eligible for contract rates.`. I will post the solution as soon as I resolve this.